# Gradle: How to specify architecture for each dependency

Tags: android, gradle, dependency-management

Let's say I have 2 libraries. `Lib.aar` supports only `ARMv7` architecture and `Lib64.aar` supports only `ARM64` architecture. How can I tell gradle that it should include each library only to its corresponding build?

Currently my `build.gradle` includes them like this.

```
dependencies {
    implementation(name: 'Lib', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'Lib64', ext:'aar')
}
```

Comment: I'm really interested too!

Answer (score 1):

I still have not been able to do what I asked. However, I did find a workaround for my problem. Since `aar` file is basically a zip library, I threw both versions of the library into one `aar` file. Then, I let the builder decide which version to include in which build by itself.